# How can I print multiple outputs from a Jupyter Notebook cell in a file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Well, I think this is new here and I'm not even sure if this is possible. But I have a loop in a Jupyter Notebook cell which generates several graphs. I was wondering if there is a way to make all these graphics appear in a file like a pdf or something?

More or less like this:

```
d = {'group': ['A', 'B','A', 'B','A', 'B','A', 'B'], 'col2': [3, 4,3,4,5,6,5,10]}
example = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def plot_func(array):
    plt.plot(array)
    plt.savefig()

for i in range(len(example.group.unique())):
    plot_func(example[example['group']==example.group.unique()[i]]['col2'])
```

But instead of saving several graphs separately, I'd like to save all in a place like a pdf document. I have two scripts doing this, but one of them is using Seaborn. So if you know a more generic answer I'd appreciate. If not, it's ok, anything would be of a great help.

Another way of explaining would be: how to print all outputs from a cell in a pdf?

Comment: You can try using [matplotlib subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to have each of the graphs you are making on the same figure, then save that to a single file as you would any other graph.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work. Inside the function there's more I didn't show. For instance, I calculate the quantiles and then plot a categorical graph where each box is a quantile. So I'm not sure your advice would work because every time the function would reset the canvas. Won't it?

Comment: You don't need to generate the figure and axes inside the function. You can create them both first and then iterate over your data, populating the subplot axes as you go. Edit: Check out [this gallery of examples](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) utilizing matplotlib subplots.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the jupyter notebook through chrome and a simple method is to save it in a pdf through printing the page in that way all the workings in the that particular file in the notebook will be recorded in the pdf.
page>right click> print> save pdf